# How to get <select> options either (value or text) using jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have a code for

```
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>Option A</option>
    <option value='2'>Option B</option>
    <option value='3'>Option C</option>
</select>
```

and i want that how ever i select any option, it will show in an alert message.
i have try

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    //var value = $("#list option[value=2]").text();
    //var value = $("#list option:selected").text();
    //var value = $('#list').val();
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);

</script>
```

but fail.

Comment: Have you wrapped your script in `$(document).ready()` before calling it? Because some of the commented line look like they'd work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Sarfraz Ahmed

but u mistakenly forgot to add # ie:

```
$('#select_box_id').change(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

again thanks Yar..

Answer (score 0):

Add the **name attribute** to the select tag.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#list").change(function() {
            var k = $("#list option[value=" + $(this).val() +"]").text();
            alert(k);
        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<select id="list" name="list">
    <option value="1">Option A</option>
    <option value="2">Option B</option>
    <option value="3">Option C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#select_box_id').change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Comment: Thanks.
it returns value of selected option great.
but to get text when i use 
   alert($(this).text());
it returns all text like:

    Option A
    Option B
    Option C
...?
but again thanks friend....   ;)

Comment: sorry i see ur name later then post comments 
if u r really a Muslim then first i want to say u Salam...
great yar

Comment: but
$('#select_box_id').change(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
  });

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't get much easier than this. Is also already optimized for speed

```
$("select#list").change(function() {
    alert($("> option:selected", this).text());
});
```